# How to set request header while Including dynamica JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, http-headers

I would like to set request header for while dynamically including javascript file , is it possible to set headers while including dynamic javascript file , [code resource](http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2008/06/01/dynamically-including-javascript-and-css-files/)

```
function includeJavascript(src) {
        if (document.createElement && document.getElementsByTagName) {
            var head_tag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
            script_tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            script_tag.setAttribute('src', src);
            head_tag.appendChild(script_tag);
        }
    }
    // Include javascript src file
    includeJavascript("http://www.mydomain.com/script/mynewscript.js");
```

for eg i would like to set these headers

```
  setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store");
  setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `response` from? And what is responding on what request?

Comment: I don't think you can set the header for the server response on the client. You need to do it on the server.

Comment: can we make use of setRequestHeader ...

Comment: Setting headers isn't possible using a `script` tag. You can do it using `XMLHttpRequest` though. Be aware that using `XMLHttpRequest` to load scripts does not work with any of the script debuggers out there.